# Xml and Json parser to map java

Tags: java, json, xml, xml-parsing

I have an application that receives data type json or xml, and I am looking for a library that allows me to parsed from json to Map  and from an xml also to Map  (and viseversa).

I currently use the gson and xstream libraries, but I would prefer to rely on a single library that can do those tasks.

If it could be something simple and that works, with gson for example I only use:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String request = "{'name':'anyName', 'age':'anyAge'}";
Map<String, String> jsonMapped = gson.fromJson(request, Map.class);
```

I know that this question has already been answered, but the answers are old and there should be a library that works in a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Jackson can do both JSON and XML now (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml). If you are dead set on using a single library that can do both that might be worth checking out.

If you are ok with using a separate library for XML and you are looking for something simple. Might I suggest SimpleXml:

```
public class MyObject {
    String name;
}

final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final MyObject object = simple.fromXml("<myobject><name>test</name></myobject>");
System.out.println(object.name);
```

Will output:

```
test
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The library won't be able to deserialize to a Map directly, but you can always wrap it in a class.